# How do I deauthorize all computers on iTunes?

Tags: itunes, windows

In older versions of iTunes (for Windows at least), there used to be a way to Deauthorize all computers associated with an account.

Now it appears the only option in 10 (10.1.2.17) is to *Deauthorize this computer...* and removes only the one I'm on. Has the option to Deauthorize All disappeared or has it been moved somewhere else?

My reason behind needing this: One of the authorized computers had a hard drive failure and I just wanted to clean up the computers I have authorized.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1420) Apple Support article you can do it from your account.

> If you find you have reached 5 authorizations, you can reset your authorization count by clicking Deauthorize All in the Account Information screen.

The process works as follows

> - Click iTunes Store in the menu on the left side of iTunes.
> - If you're not signed in to the store, click the Account button, then enter your account name and password.
> - Click the Account button again (your ID appears on the button), enter your password, and then click View Account.
> - In the Account Information window, click Deauthorize All.

[image: iTunes De-Authorize]

Also note the following:

> You may only use this feature once per year. The Deauthorize All button will not appear if you have fewer than 5 authorized computers, or if you have used this option within the last 12 months. If you need assistance on using this feature please contact iTunes Store support via email.

Comment: Thank you! Strange that they limit it to only show when you have reached 5 authorizations. I could see that being a problem if a computer were stolen, etc.

Comment: @DoozerBlake it's a nice feature in my opinion. Why show everyone a control when there is no problem. Only when you are blocked, do you even need to be offered the switch to remedy the situation. This prevents premature clearing.